# How to check a login password against a hashed password in PHP

Tags: php, database, hash, authentication, passwords

Does anyone have a generic method/function for checking a login password against a hashed password in a database?
I've seen some examples but it's not clear how they are meant to work in practice i.e.:
"To check if password $pass (from user login form usually) fits the database saved hash $hash."

password_verify($pass, $hash)

Is this $hash pulled from the database and if so what is the method for accomplishing this?
Any help advice is appreciated.

I've tried using this login function: someone suggested I use Hash::check but this throws a fatal error on undefined function.

```
public function login($username = null, $password = null) {
 $user=$this->find($username);
if($user) {
 if($this->data()->password === Hash::make($password, $this->data()->salt)){

} 
}
}
```

Comment: You need to pull it from wherever you stored it.

Comment: what you want actually?

Comment: You hash the password save it in the database. when the user logs back in you hash the inputted password and compare it with the one stored in the db

Comment: convert your inputted  password to hash and compare it.

Comment: You  use the StackOverflow search box at the top of this page and type in "PHP password hash"  :)  ... or look at all the "related" links at the bottom right of the page.  But next time you can do the search first.

Comment: I've searched this topic extensively before posting and tried some of the solutions, none of which were of any practical use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to first check the email of the user and then match the password against it.

```
function login($email,$password){
    global $connection;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE email = '$email'";

    $result_set=mysqli_query($connection,$query);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result_set) === 1) {
            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_set);
            if (password_verify($password, $row['password'])) {
                $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['id'];
                redirect_to("welcome.php");
            }else{
                echo " <script>alert('Password is incorrect');</script>  ";
            }
        }else{
            echo " <script>alert('No email found: {$email}');</script>  ";
        }


}

$email = mysqli_real_escape_string (  $connection,  $_POST['email']);
$password= mysqli_real_escape_string (  $connection,  $_POST['password']);
login($email,$password);
```

Comment: Thanks for this Saad, this looks more realistic than some of the other solutions which seem to avoid sql queries entirely.  I will report back asap.

Comment: @screencast If it works for you then select it as accepted answer

Comment: It would be better not to escape the password, one can use it directly with the `password_verify($_POST['password'])` function. Escaping for the wrong purpose bites back eventually.